# Find a value inside the document

Tags: mongodb

I'm facing difficulty to create a Find sentence to bring me just the keys and values - not the entire document. The document appear like this. I'm trying to retrieve JUST the name and code based on a code criteria. Example: When I place something like `{"code" : { $in : ["js" , "dns"}} , {"name"}}`
I'd like to receive something like...

```
[
{
        "code" : "js",
        "name" : "Java Script",
        "skillType" : "programming"
    },
    {
        "code" : "dns",
        "name" : "DNS",
        "skillType" : "networking"
    }
]
```

I mean: an array containing just part of the document, not the entire document - and matches my criteria. What is the correct way to use the find for this basic need?

Below is the entire document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53a1c40c9b97ebe1e5ad659e"),
"type" : "SkillSets",
"skillSet" : [ 
    {
        "code" : "js",
        "name" : "Java Script",
        "skillType" : "programming"
    }, 
    {
        "code" : "mong",
        "name" : "MongoDB",
        "skillType" : "database"
    }, 
    {
        "code" : "dns",
        "name" : "DNS",
        "skillType" : "networking"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe using the Aggregation Framework you can get pretty close:

Aggregation command, using your sample data:

```
db.collectionname.aggregate([
                             {$unwind:"$skillSet"},
                             {$match:{"skillSet.code":{$in:["dns","js"]}}}, 
                             {$project:{skillSet:1, _id:0}}, 
                             {$group: { _id: null, skill: { $push: "$$ROOT" } }}
                            ])
```

And result:

```
{
  "_id" : null, 
  "skill" : [ 
             {"skillSet" : { "code" : "js", "name" : "Java Script", "skillType" : "programming" } }, 
             {"skillSet" : { "code" : "dns", "name" : "DNS", "skillType" : "networking" } } 
            ] 
}
```

You'll want to experiment a bit with your full data set to get the exact results you need. More on the aggregation framework here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/